# Dynamic Group Security in Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I've reviewed the documentation for Group Security for Firebase Storage where it suggests to use custom tokens or including group information in file metadata, however, when a user leaves a group, I don't ideally want to be updating the metadata in every file or having to create a new folder and update the group token information.

If this were the Realtime Database, I'd check to see if the user was still a group member. Is there a more elegant solution along these lines that I can explore?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

yeah with custom tokens you can associate additional attributes with the user. The trick is when you create custom token for a given user id, you can add additional claims and use them to evaluate the access rules. In your case you can add the group id to which the user belongs as additional claim when the token is created on your server using which the user logs-in from the client app. So whenever the user leaves your group, his group id association is removed and hence when you recreate the token for that user, you will no more associate the group id in additional claims.
Sample Example

```
public static String createCustomToken(String userId, Map<String, Object> additionalClaims) {
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
.setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream(FIREBASE_ACCESS_FILE)).build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
Task<String> customToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(userId, additionalClaims);
return customToken.getResult().toString();
}
```